# A "squared-off" log or a large, oblong piece of timber, metal, or stone used especially as a horizontal support in construction

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "squared-off" in

> [a squared-off log or a large, oblong piece of timber, metal, or stone used especially as a horizontal support in construction](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beam#:%7E:text=9.-,a.,protons%3B%20a%20beam%20of%20light.)
> ( Definition of "Beam" from *the free dictionary*)

mean to make something such as an edge or corner straight? In other words, does it mean "not curved or crooked" in this context? Thank you!

Comment: A log, being a piece of tree, is roughly cylindrical. A beam is roughly square in cross-section. So to make one into the other you have to cut off four sections of the curved surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A log, being a piece of tree, is roughly cylindrical. A beam is
> roughly square in cross-section. So to make one into the other you
> have to cut off four sections of the curved surface. –  Kate Bunting

These logs have been partly squared-off:

[image]

Comment: Including Kate's comment would provide a textual explanation as well as the graphical explanation.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your explanations!